# How to increase the session performance when reading huge data table in informatica

Tags: oracle, informatica

I have one to one mapping with huge source oracle table with more than 300 million of rows and i am writing into a csv file. table has 11 columns.
i have added 10 pass through partitions on primary key at informatica level.

Following is the source query used at first partition QUERY

```
SELECT  /*+PARALLEL(10)*/ 
 ORDER_AUDIT_DETAIL_KEY,
 ORDER_AUDIT_KEY,
 ORDER_AUDIT_LEVEL_KEY,
 AUDIT_XML,
 CREATETS,
 MODIFYTS,
 CREATEUSERID,
 MODIFYUSERID,
 CREATEPROGID,
 MODIFYPROGID,
 LOCKID
FROM $ParamOwnerName.T_ORDER_AUDIT_DETAIL
WHERE SUBSTR(ORDER_AUDIT_DETAIL_KEY,-1,1) IN ('0') #this value varies From 0 to 9 for each partition respectively.
```

session is taking 17 hours to complete the data load. 
can anyone please suggest something to improve the performance?

Comment: Do you have an index for `SUBSTR(ORDER_AUDIT_DETAIL_KEY,-1,1)` on your table T_ORDER_AUDIT_DETAIL?

Comment: Yes  table has UNIQUE Index  on ORDER_AUDIT_DETAIL_KEY.

Comment: No that index could not be used for your query. Try to add an index on SUBSTR(ORDER_AUDIT_DETAIL_KEY,-1,1), it might not help much but that could speed up the query a bit...

Comment: How big is the AUDIT_XML field... if you have 10 columns and one of them is a clob then the record is very big and you're bound to hit resource issues at the db

Comment: i increased the data size of  AUDIT_XML field from 4000 to 999999.. it improved permanence a bit.

Comment: This seems to be even worse than Round Robin... Can you make a test run with false filter before the target and share the performance results? Can you share the thread brakedown (at the end of a log file)?

Comment: Can you not reduce the size of the source data by filtering on CREATETS or MODIFYTS?